# Can you create a database in cpanel for sqlyog?

Tags: mysql, cpanel, sqlyog

I've created a database in cpanel and i was wondering if i could use it in SQLyog. Whenever i enter the database user and database password im getting and access denied error in the client. Should i be using different credentials to the ones created in the MySQL database wizard? I also have all the privileges checked.

Thank you all for you help!

Comment: Shouldnt be a reason why not, its a third party application a bit like mysql workbench and that connects fine. Are you certain you have the ports correct?

Comment: Make sure that the user you created/that has access to that new database has an ip or ip range that matches your sqlyog client's ip. For instance, in mysql, you'll usually have a user `root@localhost` that allows you to get in as root, but only when you come into the mysql server from the same computer as the server is running on (localhost, or  192.168.1.1).

Comment: @JNevill It is a remote MySQL server, i'm not running it on my machine.. is there anything i need to do different as it is not on my machine?

Comment: Like I said, you need to insure that the user in MySQL that you are connecting with is allowing your remote IP to connect to it. In mysql a user is user@clientaddress. You can specify a range for that address, or just toss a % in as the client address to allow any ip to connect (which is not a super great idea). You can check out the documentation [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/account-names.html)